# How to do batch conversion from Adobe RGB to Srgb

Tags: post-processing, color-spaces, adobe-rgb

I have a lot of pictures (almost a full 4gb memory card) that I accidentally shot in Adobe RGB on my Sony SLT a35.
Will Adobe RGB images look different or unrealistic if seen/displayed on a monitor (and not printed)? That is, if I'm not printing, should I bother to convert all of them? And is the a way to batch convert these images to SRGB ? I am using Adobe Photoshop CS2 and Sony's software, Windows 10.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you shooting raw or JPEG?

Comment: @michael clark I'm shooting JPEG

Comment: then cmason pretty well has it covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you review the top answer to this question: [How do color spaces like sRGB and Adobe RGB overlap?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14272/how-do-color-spaces-like-srgb-and-adobe-rgb-overlap) you will see that the sRGB color space is completely within the Adobe RGB color space. Therefore, there should be no issues with 'missing' or odd colors. However, it you are going to display on the web, most assume sRGB color profile, so it could look washed out, depending on whether color management is supported. To avoid these issues, its best to convert.

To do so in Photoshop, simply choose Edit> Convert to Profile. Change the destination space to sRGB. (I believe CS2 menus still look like this).

To do this via Batch, simply use Image Processor: File>Scripts>Image Processor. Select the item: 'Convert Profile to sRGB'.

Comment: Oh, so if I keep them in Adobe RGB and view them in windows photo viewer in a monitor, they'll look the same as if I convert them to SRGB?

Comment: Depends on your monitor and software. This gets into a much broader question about color management, so I encourage you to search Photography.SE for info on that.  In general, all software and monitors can support sRGB as the lowest common denominator, so when you want to display on the web or monitors, its a good idea to have images in that color space, especially if you don't control the monitor or software (you send someone an image). There is nothing wrong with Adobe RGB, only if others don't support it, the image may not look like you see it to others.

Comment: There's no mention of a batch conversion in this answer.

Comment: @ths updated per your comment

Comment: Thanks for the batch edit. I've been coming across this for a long time but didn't actually know what it did.