# Image Color Scheme getting faded when opening with MSPaint

Tags: color, camera-settings, color-correction, color-spaces

I have the following image (have put a screen-grab of the image as its size is more than 2 MB - the original can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rC2QQBzMhZ8AG5Lp5PyrpkOxwlyP9QaE/view?usp=sharing

[image]

When i open the image in MSPaint the image color get faded.Why does this happen? Is this because of Color depth change or something ? Please advice

[image]

Comment: [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) supports color profiles and is free, but will be a culture shock to someone that comes from MSPaint (but so would PS, possibly)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a PC I could run MSPaint on to test or provide a 'fix' but I'm betting it doesn't know how to handle the ProPhoto profile that's embedded in the picture & is treating it as though it were sRGB.
It suffers the same colour loss if I open it in Photoshop & assign an sRGB profile without any colour management. You likely need a better [smarter] app to handle it.

Here's a mockup [translated properly to sRGB] of how each looks if the app understands or doesn't understand ProPhoto…

[image]

As for suggestions as to what will be able to handle it properly - I don't use Windows, so don't know what's available. [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), as mentioned by xenoid, is cross-platform & very capable… but not the easiest app to throw yourself into.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer to the question asked is... because of the [colour profile](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2624) embedded in the photo (which it appears Microsoft Paint doesn't read/respect).

Answer (score 0):

The color profile of your image is **ProPhoto RGB** which is a wide gamut color profile. Most low-end photo viewers and editors don't handle anything but **sRGB** color profile. When viewing a wide gamut image in sRGB space, the colors look dingy. When you're done editing your image in a wide gamut color space, you should convert to sRGB so the average person can view your images.

BTW, Microsoft has the worst multimedia programs.

Comment: I'd suggest that this answer can be improved by expanding on what you mean by "dingy", by discussing _how_ to convert to sRGB (and what options are available in the conversion), and also I think it's not helpful to make subjective claims about software from any particular vendor without backing it up with some data/experience/examples.